# Aggregate/join/concatenate a LinkedList object to a string - Java

Tags: java

How can I use String.join or some alternative to join the items in a LinkedList with a delimiter, to output a string?

Id rather not create my own method as I feel there should be something implemented in Java itself that should be able to handle this.

EDIT:

How can this be done in a NICE way on a `LinkedList<Integer>` type?

Specifically using the `String.join` method if possible

Comment: `list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Answer (score 3):

As [andy-turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) mention in his comment, you can use functional approach:

```
list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Also you can use:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
String result = String.join(",", list);
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/ihabGC)

Comment: Using the 2nd method, can it be done using a LinkedList?

Comment: @Alej, yes. I updated my answer with a java demo link https://ideone.com/ihabGC

Comment: I keep getting this when trying to use String.join on a LinkedList<Integer>, Cannot resolve method 'join(java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.Integer>)' - do I need to change it to a LinkedList<String>? If so, how can do this in a nice way?

Comment: @Alej Why don't you **look at the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to see what type of object the second argument can support. --- Hmmm... Seems it takes an `Iterable`. Is `LinkedList` an `Iterable`? *(Hint: see its javadoc)* --- Is the element type in the list a `CharSequence`? *(Hint: `String` is, `Integer` is not)*

Comment: But how can you then do this on a LinkedList<Integer> type in a nice way? In C# you can just use LINQ/lambda to easily aggregate the elements together and convert them to a string at the same time, 1 line of code.

Comment: @Alej I like the 1st functional approach... but if for some reason you want to use `String.join` then you will have to convert the list previously... like:
`String.join(",", list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));`